# Array de condições SQL - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

boa tarde, estou mandando um filtro de busca para meu BD, e quero fazer essas condições dentro de um array, por exemplo:

```
$condicoes = array();

$nome = $_GET['nome'];
if (!empty($nome)) {
    $condicoes = ("nome" => $nome);
}
$tipoAnimal = $_GET['tipoAnimal'];
if (!empty($tipoAnimal)) {
    $condicoes = ("tipoAnimal" => $tipoAnimal);
}   
$raca = $_GET['raca'];
if (!empty($raca)) {
    $condicoes = ("raca" => $raca);
}       
$tamanho = $_GET['tamanho'];
if (!empty($tamanho)) {
    $condicoes = ("tamanho" => $tamanho);
}       
$sexo = $_GET['sexo'];
if (!empty($sexo)) {
    $condicoes = ("sexo" => $sexo);
}       
$estado = $_GET['estado'];
if (!empty($estado)) {
    $condicoes = ("estado" => $estado);
}       
$cidade = $_GET['cidade'];
if (!empty($cidade)) {
    $condicoes = ("cidade" => $cidade);
}
```

ai no final faria um implode eu axo, para colocar o `AND` para que na query fique:

```
SELECT * FROM nome_tabela WHERE $condicoes;
```

Answer (score 9):

Sim, você pode usar implode/join, mas seu código está muito repetido, um jeito mais simples de fazer isso é:

```
$keys = array('nome', 'tipoAnimal', 'raca', 'tamanho', 'sexo', 'estado', 'cidade');

$conditions = array();

foreach($keys as $key) {
    $val = $_GET[$key];
    if (!empty($val)) {
        $conditions[] = "$key = '$val'";
    }
}

$full_conditions = join(" AND ", $conditions);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM nome_tabela" . (empty($full_conditions) ? "": " WHERE $full_conditions;");
```

Essa resposta vale apenas para busca por igualdade no banco de dados, não daria para fazer algo do tipo `select * from tabela where nome like '%foo%'`, sugiro que você leia sobre ORMs em PHP[0].

[0] http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapeamento_objeto-relacional

Comment: Nesse caso teria que verificar ali, caso o `$full_conditions` estiver vazio para não adicionar o `WHERE` no SQL, senão vai dar erro na consulta.

Answer (score 4):

Uma alternativa similar à [do @Peoplee](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/31556/250) mas que não sofre da limitação descrita por ele é popular o array em pequenos fragmentos, seguindo uma lógica pré-especificada pela Aplicação:

```
/**
 * Trata os dados de $_POST, sanitizando as informações e removendo
 * vazios e inválidos, como Estado (ver a ER e a forma de aplicação no link abaixo)
 *
 * @see http://jsfiddle.net/brunoaugusto/6fV6C/
 */
$data = array( 'tipoAnimal' => 'cachorro', 'estado' => 'SP', 'cidade' => 'Nova' );

$clauses = array();

if( array_key_exists( 'tipoAnimal', $data ) ) {
    $clauses[] = sprintf( '`tipoAnimal` = "%s"', $data['tipoAnimal'] );
}

if( array_key_exists( 'estado', $data ) ) {
    $clauses[] = sprintf( '`estado` = "%s"', $data['estado'] );
}

// Aqui nós variamos o formato

if( array_key_exists( 'cidade', $data ) ) {
    $clauses[] = sprintf( '`cidade` LIKE "%%%s%%"', $data['cidade'] );
}

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `tabela`';

if( count( $clauses ) > 0 ) {

    $query .= implode( ' AND ', $clauses );
}

echo $query;
```

Assim, caso o dado seja informado e venha em **$_POST** e passe por qualquer filtro ou validação que você venha a definir, a query será dinamicamente construída.

Porém, mesmo mais flexível, essa abordagem ainda tem uma limitação que é o de implicar o uso da cláusula AND para todas as condições. Você pode trocar pela cláusula OR ou manter como está, depende da lógica da sua Aplicação.

Apenas a título de curiosidade, esse tipo de problema não ocorre em frameworks de domínio específico, como Doctrine, por exemplo pois neles você normalmente faz algo como (não se atenha á sintaxe):

```
$select = new Select( 'tipoAnimal', 'estado', 'cidade' );

$select ->      from( 'tabela' )
        ->     where( 'tipoAnimal = ?', $data['tipoAnimal'] )
        ->     where( 'estado = ?',     $data['estado'] )
        ->   orwhere( 'cidade LIKE ?',  $data['cidade'] ); // Esse aqui será um OR
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma coisa bem básica e didática seria assim:

```
$condicoes = array();

$nome = 'bidu';

if (isset($nome)) {
    $condicoes["nome"] = $nome;
}
$tipoAnimal = 'cachorro';
if (isset($tipoAnimal)) {
    $condicoes["tipoAnimal"] = $tipoAnimal;
}   


$where = "";
$i = 1;
foreach($condicoes as $key => $c){
    if($i == 1){
        $where .= "$key like '%$c%' ";
    }else{
        $where .= "and $key like '%$c%' ";
    }
    $i++;
}

echo "SELECT * FROM nome_tabela WHERE $where";
```

Nesse caso o exibido na tela foi o seguinte:

```
SELECT * FROM nome_tabela WHERE nome like '%bidu%' and tipoAnimal like '%cachorro%'
```

Comment: É bem isso mesmo, eu só faria uma pequena alteração que seria: `$where .= "{$key} like '%{$c}%' AND ";` e depois do loop colocava um `rtrim($where,' AND ')` pra evitar fazer __n__ comparações (o que pode prejudicar a performance quando o loop é muito grande).

Comment: Você está passando uma informação errada quanto ao `empty`. O `empty`serve para verificar se a variável está vazia ou é zero, e se aplica a uma série de usos além do _array_. Inclusive, em algumas ocasiões que é melhor para checar parâmetros do que `isset` (não estou falando especificamente do caso do OP). Veja mais em: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.empty.php

Answer (score 2):

Considere utilizar uma biblioteca para gestão do banco de dados. ;)

[ConnectionMSi](https://github.com/KaduAmaral/ConnectionMSi)

Ai você poderia fazer algo como:

```
$keys = array('nome', 'sexo', 'estado', 'cidade', 'fone');
$where = Array();
foreach ($keys as $key)
   if (!empty($_REQUEST[$key]))
      $where[$key] = $_REQUEST[$key];

$resultado = $con->Select('nome_tabela', $where);
```